# Explain why any composite three-digit number is divisible by at least one of the primes 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am not really sure where to begin here. First idea that came to mind was proof by contradiction but I am not even sure if that is the right route.

Comment: Note: $\sqrt{1000} = 31.6$.  This is relevant!  How?

Comment: Hint:  if $n$ is composite, it has a nontrivial factor $≤\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 6):

Let the composite number be $n$. Let it be factorized as $$n=ab$$ where $a,b\gt1$. This is possible because $n$ is composite.

Now, suppose the above is not true. Then, $a\gt31$ and $b\gt31$. Then,
$a\ge32$ and $b\ge32$. Then,
$$n=ab\ge32^2=1024$$
But $n\lt1000$. Thus, this is a contradiction. Every three digit composite number must be divisible by at least one prime $\lt32$. And the list mentions all such primes.

Comment: So the fact that n is 3-digit doesn't matter? That's what's throwing me off about this proof

Comment: @bunsbun12 it does matter, all three-digit numbers are smaller than $1000$, that's where the contradiction is at

Comment: @bunsbun12 $n$ is 3 digit that's why $n\lt1000$

Comment: Okay thank you! So essentially I could use contradiction but it not using contradiction be valid as well?

Suppose n is a three digit composite number
since n is composite there are integers a ,b such that ab=n
and n has a prime divisor less than or equal to n^(1/2).
Therefore a or b must be primes greater than or equal to 31 because
sqrt(1000)=31.6

is this valid

OR am I better off going the contradiction route

Comment: @bunsbun12 Your idea is correct. You just would need to show that at least one prime factor must be greater than $\sqrt{1000}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=a\cdot b\leq999$ with $1<a\leq b$. Then $a^2\leq a\cdot b\leq 999$, hence $1<a\leq31$. It follows that $a$, and therefore $n$, is divisible by a prime $\leq31$.